# C# based docker application to download files from blob storage on host system

Tags: c#, docker

I am trying to download an exe file from azure blob storage and store it on host system using a deodorized container application. I am writing code by creating a .netcore project in VS2017. this is how my program.cs looks like:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Mqtt;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DocumentFromBlob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The Edge runtime gives us the connection string we need -- it is injected as an environment variable
            // string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EdgeHubConnectionString");
            string connectionString = "namehost";
            // Cert verification is not yet fully functional when using Windows OS for the container
            bool bypassCertVerification = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);
            //  if (!bypassCertVerification) InstallCert();
            Init(connectionString, bypassCertVerification).Wait();

            // Wait until the app unloads or is cancelled
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += (ctx) => cts.Cancel();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, cpe) => cts.Cancel();
            WhenCancelled(cts.Token).Wait();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles cleanup operations when app is cancelled or unloads
        /// </summary>
        public static Task WhenCancelled(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).SetResult(true), tcs);
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add certificate in local cert store for use by client for secure connection to IoT Edge runtime
        /// </summary>
        static void InstallCert()
        {
            string certPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EdgeModuleCACertificateFile");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certPath))
            {
                // We cannot proceed further without a proper cert file
                Console.WriteLine($"Missing path to certificate collection file: {certPath}");
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing path to certificate file.");
            }
            else if (!File.Exists(certPath))
            {
                // We cannot proceed further without a proper cert file
                Console.WriteLine($"Missing path to certificate collection file: {certPath}");
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing certificate file.");
            }
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(certPath)));
            Console.WriteLine("Added Cert: " + certPath);
            store.Close();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the DeviceClient and sets up the callback to receive
        /// messages containing temperature information
        /// </summary>
        static async Task Init(string connectionString, bool bypassCertVerification = false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection String {0}", connectionString);

            MqttTransportSettings mqttSetting = new MqttTransportSettings(TransportType.Mqtt_Tcp_Only);
            // During dev you might want to bypass the cert verification. It is highly recommended to verify certs systematically in production
            if (bypassCertVerification)
            {
                mqttSetting.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            }
            ITransportSettings[] settings = { mqttSetting };

            // Open a connection to the Edge runtime
            DeviceClient ioTHubModuleClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, settings);
            await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("IoT Hub module client initialized.");

            // Register callback to be called when a message is received by the module
            // await ioTHubModuleClient.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync("input1", PipeMessage, ioTHubModuleClient);

            // Attach callback for Twin desired properties updates
            //  await ioTHubModuleClient.SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync(onDesiredPropertiesUpdate, null);

            // Register callback to be called when a message is received by the module
            //  await ioTHubModuleClient.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync("input1", FilterMessages, ioTHubModuleClient);


            DownloadFile();
        }
        public static async void DownloadFile()
        {
            string filename = "RDM_WorkFlow.pdf";
            string destinationFile = @"D:\Test";
            byte[] data = await DownloadFileFromBlob(filename);

            WriteFile(filename, data, destinationFile);
        }
        public static async Task<byte[]> DownloadFileFromBlob(string FileName)
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = BlobUtilities.GetBlobClient.GetContainerReference("documents");
            // Get reference to blob (binary content)
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName);
            try
            {
                //await   blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(@"D:\Test", FileMode.Create);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                byte[] bt = null;
                return bt;
            }
        }

        public static void WriteFile(string fileName, byte[] bytes, string path)
        {
            // string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            try
            {
                var fullpath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Test", fileName);

                if (File.Exists(fullpath))
                {

                    File.Delete(fullpath);
                }

                //// Create the file.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fullpath))
                {

                }
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                //write to file
                FileStream file = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                ms.WriteTo(file);
                file.Close();
                ms.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }

        }

    }
    internal class BlobUtilities
    {
        public static CloudBlobClient GetBlobClient
        {
            get
            {
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("XYZ;"
                 + "AccountKey=+abc=");
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                return blobClient;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i get exception in WriteFile function. I modified docker-compose.yml file to share host file system which is directory in C:/Test.

```
    version: '3'

services:
  documentfromblob:
    image: documentfromblob
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DocumentFromBlob/Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - /C/Test
```

it should copy the file from my blob to C:/Test directory but it throws exception. i can do it using docker run command but i want this container to perform sharing of file system with host directly and copy a file to host system. i suppose it should be done by modifying .yml file. am i missing something?

Comment: Add the exception message.

Comment: Thanks for replying here you go:ex = {System.IO.IOException: Invalid argument
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   a...

Comment: when i run container i get following error Could not find a part of the path '/app/E:\Test/RDM_WorkFlow.pdf'.
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at DocumentFromBlob.Program.WriteFile(String fileName, Byte[] bytes, String path) in /src/DocumentFromBlob/Program.cs:line 159